# Online survey webapp that takes participants names but does not link with their answers

Tags: gratis, web-apps, survey

It’s a requirement in an educational institute where we want students to fill the survey before releasing the results:

- Take the names, to see who has filled the survey or not.
- But does not show what each person has answered (to preserve answer anonymity).

Comment: That's not how it usually works: Usually you invite per email, thus ensuring only the relevant people get a link. Each student gets an individual link (an ID only), so everyone can only participate once. This also ensures anonymity, because you don't enter the name during the survey

Comment: If such an approach is acceptable, see https://www.limesurvey.org/. To have it really proofable anonymous, you'd just invite yourself a number of times, print out the links and pass on the links on paper. Students could interchange them (with the effect that one student could fill out all the surveys).